# Laravel how to get only one record per user

Tags: php, laravel

In my `laravel`-application, I want to display all users/candidates, which have taken an education. Now it might happen, that a user/candidate has taken more than one education, so in this case, just the latest education should be displayed.

I've come to this:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
    $q->where('slug', 'candidate');
}
)->whereHas('educations')
 ->join('user_educations', 'user_educations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
 ->join('educations', 'user_educations.education_id', '=', 'educations.id')
 ->join('education_levels', 'user_educations.education_level_id', '=', 'education_levels.id')
 ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.surname', 'users.status', 'users.city', 'users.zipcode', 'users.birthday', 'users.avatar', 'educations.title as education', 'education_levels.title as education_level')
 ->where('user_educations.user_id', '=', 'users.id') // HERE IT FAILS - returns null
 ->first();

return response(['success' => true, "users" => $users], 200);
```

when I leave out the `where('user_educations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')`-clause, and do `get()` instead of `first()`, I get all users/candidates with educations, and also sometimes the same user multiple times, depending on how many educations he has taken.

how can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Rwd Laravel 5.8

Comment: I'm not sure why you want the last `where` (the failing one) since the `join('user_educations', ...)` will take care of that for you. Also, just an FYI, if you're wanting to  add a `where` clause to compare two columns you can use `whereColumn`. As for getting only the latest education, you could always create a `hasOne` relationship on your `User` model that gets the latest `Education` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The distinct method allows you to force the query to return distinct results, you can use it like this;

```
$users = DB::table('users')->groupBy('user_id')->distinct()->get();
```

If you want to take just the latest record, you should use "orderBy" to order your records, than pick a record with something like this :

```
$users = DB::table('users')->groupBy('user_id')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->distinct()->get();
```

You can look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries) for more detailed information about query builders in Laravel